# Can a Chapter have up to 500 words

Tags: wordcount, chapters

So far I am writing my fiction historical novel. It is being narrated in bits and pieces.

Hence, story is NOT in chronological order. As Person is being interviewed, story is being narrated.

First chapter is roughly 400 words

Second chapter is roughly 300 words

When I google, it says chapter must be 5,000 words!

But these chapters are in separate sections of their own.

Comment: See the answers in the linked question, but chapter length depends greatly on genre and pacing and doesn't need to always be the same even within the same book.

Answer (score 3):

It can have as many pages as you want , that’s up to you